# Reliable redis hosting from NodeJitsu

Tags: redis, nodejitsu

I'm looking for a reliable Redis hosting solution for NodeJitsu.

IrisCouch has proved unreliable as a Redis host (though its been excellent for CouchDB). I'm looking for a better alternative.

One consideration is that Nodejitsu is on Joyent, so to reduce latency it would be ideal to be hosted in the same data center. I see that [openredis.com](https://openredis.com/docs/regions) has an option for Joyent (us-east-1).

Has anyone had a positive experience using NodeJitsu with openredis.com or any other affordable Redis hosts out there (e.g. redis-cloud.com, redis4you.com etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with http://redistogo.com/ in the past through heroku, I consider them to be a reliable option in case you want to check them out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I should have mentioned that one of the reasons I've been looking for a replacement is that redistogo had some serious problems a few months back and in fact NodeJitsu now disables that option in their UI with a "provider currently inactive" flag. But maybe its time to give them another chance -- not on anything production level though!